# Performance issue in play application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a play(2.3.0) application that does some database lookups. When there are more than 6 users the application runs into performance problems.

I have narrowed down the problem to a controller with an action that does a sleep of 4 seconds. 
A test client calls this action every 500 ms. I can see the the first 6 requests are processesed, and it stops a few seconds(until the 4 seconds sleep have passed) and reads the next 6.

Also: when I open 7 browser windows the 7th will not load(waits for connection).

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools) it looks like my problem is blocking io and using the highly synchronous profile should solve my problem.
Therefore I added this profile to my application.conf but nothing changes.

my application.conf looks like this

```
application.context=/appname/


# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
# If you deploy your application to several instances be sure to use the same key!
application.secret="xxxxx"


play {
  akka {
    akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-min = 300
          parallelism-max = 300
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the action

```
  def performancetestSleep() = Action{ request => {
    Thread.sleep(4000)
    Ok("hmmm good sleep")
  }}
```

It seems to me the threadpool configuration is ignored. What am I missing here?

Comment: Thread.sleep is a thread blocking action, so it isn't good at all. Probably you have a cpu that handles 6 threads in parallel, do you know the core's numbers and threads your cpu has?

Answer (score 0):

What you need for this is really just one thread which handles the 4 second delay - a scheduler. Spawning that many threads defeats the whole point of the architecture that Play has, IMHO. You could then use the scheduler to create a `Future[Result]` which you'd feed into an `Action.async` block.

Now, you don't really need to implement your own scheduler since Play depends on Akka for its concurrency; and Akka has a scheduler which will do the job.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Promise}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import play.libs.Akka

val system = Akka.system()

def delayedResponse = Action.async {
  import system.dispatcher

  val promise = Promise[Result]

  system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(4000 milliseconds) {
    promise.success(Ok("Sorry for the wait!")) 
  }

  promise.future
}
```

Comment: I used the described solution because the documentation mentions to use this in a blocking environment and I have also read that using async in blocking calls does not solve the problem. Maybe I read wrong, I will give this a try anyway, tnx.

Comment: The solution that I have posted is fully asynchronous. You won't need to increase your threadpool size. My impression was that you wanted to fix the issue where the server cannot process more than 6 requests. This will fix that, at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

I used

> activator run

to start the server, that does not seem to pick up the threadpool profile. Using

> activator start

does, and now the profile seems to be used. I now need to test if this solves my problem. Will also have a look at the async call.